Setting JAVA_HOME in Mac (not personal)
I got a Mac (M3 pro) for work. I have installed Java 17 (Temurin) and Java 8 (Amazon) for a project specific requirement. Now when I tried to set the JAVA_HOME (export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.0.10/Contents/Home"), I get the following message when I try to echo $JAVA_HOME: "Using system JDK, no JAVA_HOME set!".
I am facing this problem for past 3 days. Please help me in this regard.
I was trying to set the JAVA_HOME and using the export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.0.10/Contents/Home" in .zshrc file. When running the direct export cmd in terminal as well as iTerm2 also, JAVA_HOME is not set. When I try to echo $JAVA_HOME I get the following message:

Using system JDK, no JAVA_HOME set!

I am not sure is it permissions issue on my Mac or a Java installation issue.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-macos-installation

‘when I try to echo $JAVA_HOME : Using system JDK, no JAVA_HOME set!’ I doubt echo or the variable expansion resulted in that message.

Did you do the export and echo on the same terminal?

What do you get with echo $FOOBAR?

You need to specify exactly which command you used that wrote "Using system JDK, no JAVA_HOME set!" It was not the echo command because the echo command doesn't say that. Also, specify the detailed steps: in particular, did you set JAVA_HOME in one terminal window and then tried to run something in another window?

You can use SDKMAN to install multiple version and you can change the default version when you need it.
